# SSIS XSD Definition

Tags: ssis, xsd

Where can I find the XSD for the SSIS dtsx files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it has not been published. This is from someone who worked with SSIS documentation at Microsoft.

http://dougbert.com/blogs/dougbert/archive/2008/07/19/lt-published-gt-some-of-the-xml-schemas-used-by-integration-services-lt-published-gt.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Here is all the XSD you need to work with SSIS package files.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg600473.aspx

Hope that it helps